# How to manage different maven setting in eclipse for different projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on **two different** projects, Both uses different maven `.settings.xml` files.
When I switch between the projects, it re downloads all the maven dependencies in repository folder removing previous projects' dependencies.
Is there any way I can use two `settings` and it maintains different repository for both projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to separate the two projects in **different** *workspaces* and you can configure **each** *workspace* with Eclipse. It is possible because *Eclipse saves the configuration within each workspace*. Therefore, for these *workspaces*, is possible specify different and specific repositories according with their Maven `settings.xml` files.

For to do that, launch **eclipse > go to preferences > choose maven > User Settings** and click on **"Update Settings"**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

You should have a structure similar to the following:

**Workspaces:**

```
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/workspace-project-1
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/workspace-project-2
```

**Projects:**

```
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/workspace-project-1/project-1
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/workspace-project-2/project-2
```

**Settings.xml:**

```
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/settings-project-1.xml
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/settings-project-2.xml
```

**Repositories:**

```
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/repository-1
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/repository-2
```

Open and edit **`settings-project-1.xml`** file. Searchs the **`localRepository`** tag and replace the path, for example:

```
<localRepository>/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/repository-1</localRepository>
```

Open and edit **`settings-project-2.xml`** file. Searchs the **`localRepository`** tag and replace with the other path, for example:

```
<localRepository>/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/repository-2</localRepository>
```

*Important: checks that the **`<localRepository>`** tag is not commented for example:*

```
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->  
  <localRepository>/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

**Eclipse:**

Open the **`workspace-project-1`**, go to **preferences > choose maven > User Settings** and click on **"Update Settings"** and replace with the new path:

```
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/settings-project-1.xml
```

The same way you should do for the **`workspace-project-2`**, open the **`workspace-project-2`** and go to **preferences > choose maven > User Settings** and click on **"Update Settings"** and replace with the other path:

```
/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/.m2/settings-project-2.xml
```

With this configuration each project should download the dependencies in the differents repositories.

*This configuration should work, but in case does not work, you should post your settings.xml file and the pom files of both projects, so that we can help you better*

Comment: i am doing it in same way, but the issue is that maven repository is same irrespective of the work space.  And when I switch between the work spaces, it re downloads all the maven dependencies in repository folder removing previous projects' dependencies.

Comment: In each `settings.xml` file you must change the localRepository tag, look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 separate workspaces in Eclipse. In each workspaces, you can provide respective settings.xml file

Comment: i am doing it in different works paces only, but the issue is that maven repository is same irrespective of the work space. And when I switch between the work spaces, it re downloads all the maven dependencies in repository folder removing previous projects' dependencies.

Comment: Let me ask you question. May I know, why you need two separate settings.xml file?

Comment: I worked for over 10 years as a Java programmer on multiple projects and never had more than a single repository. Why do you want multiple repositories?